# How to compare two values from a List?

Tags: list, grails, groovy

I wanted to know how to compare two values of a List.
For example, I have a `List` of Names that may contain many `values` such as `(Ana, Ben, Maria, Ana)`. From this List, since the name Ana is listed twice, it should only be inserted in the database once, otherwise it will return an error. I know that the unique constraint can solve this, but is not the requirement in the current grails project that I am working on. So how will I compare the values of my list before inserting them to my database without using the unique constraint?

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't mean you want to avoid the `unique` method in Groovy, you can do this:

```
List names = [ 'Ana', 'Ben', 'Maria', 'Ana' ]

assert names.unique(false) != names
```

That creates a new list from `names` (which is `[ 'Ana', 'Ben', 'Maria' ]`) and asserts it isn't the same as the original list.

It creates a new list as we [passed `false` to the `unique` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28boolean%29).  If you pass `true`, it will modify the original list...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a List you could use a Set, which allows no repeated elements. If you declare your names variable as a Set, it just won't be possible to add repeated elements. Everytime you look at the variable, you can be sure it's naturally filled with unique elements.

Also, if you want to convert your list to a set, you can just do:

```
def uniqueNames = names as Set
```

Comment: You don't need `as Set` if you declare the type :-)

Comment: Oops. True story. I guess what I meant was 'def'. Thanks! ;)

Comment: [@tim_yates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757122/how-to-compare-two-values-from-a-list#comment15619444_11763109) I got curious, so I tried it both ways and compared the bytecode that groovyc produces. It looks like whether you declare the type or use the `as` operator Groovy creates a List and then converts it to a Set. The only difference is that you could override the `as` operator if you had a sufficiently compelling reason to do so.